# How to clear a Terminal Screen in InfluxDB

Tags: terminal, influxdb

I need to clear the screen when using InfluxDB.

Id like to know if there's a comand similar to linux `clear` to clear the terminal window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What works for me in the `influx` command line interface (CLI) on Mac terminal is `Ctrl + L`.